# Cmake finds Eigen library but does not mark with found

Tags: compilation, cmake, eigen

I found a strange behavior with `cmake`. On my computer I have two versions of `Eigen`:

1. installed one via ubuntu repo (version **3.2.2**)
2. downloaded one (version **3.3.3**).

I have added the location of the 2. Eigen library in `$PATH`.

In the **CMakeFiles.txt** I write

```
find_package(Eigen3 3.3.3 REQUIRED)
if (NOT Eigen3_FOUND)
MESSAGE( STATUS "Eigen not found.")
endif(NOT Eigen3_FOUND)
MESSAGE( STATUS "EIGEN_DIR:         " ${Eigen3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

but it outputs the following:

```
-- Found Eigen3: /home/armena/armena/eigen3 (Required is at least version "3.3.3") 
-- Eigen not found.
-- EIGEN_DIR:
```

---

From what I understand it finds the library but it is not able to return its location. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Can you try `EIGEN3_FOUND`?

Comment: @Angew you got it. that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Eigen's package config file does not follow CMake's recommended naming guidelines; all of its variables are prefixed with `EIGEN3_`, not with `Eigen3_`. If you change your CMakeList like this, it should work:

```
if (NOT EIGEN3_FOUND)
  message( STATUS "Eigen not found.")
endif()
message( STATUS "EIGEN_DIR:         " ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```